# Filter for red hue - emgucv/opencv

Tags: opencv, emgucv

How do I filter an image for red hue? I understand that red lies around zero between 330° and 30° (represented by 165 to 15 in OpenCV?). How can I use that range with the InRange method as there is an overflow at 360° (180 in OpenCV)?

Answer (score 1):

Im detecting HUE colour using the following code:

> Mat img_hsv, dst ;
>   cap >> image;
>   cvtColor(image, img_hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);
>   inRange(img_hsv, Scalar(110, 130, 100), Scalar(140, 255, 255), dst );

where dst is Mat of the same size as img_hsv and CV_8U type.
And your scalars determine the filtered colour. In my case its:

HUE from 110 to 140
SAT from 130 to 255
VAL from 100 to 255

more info here: 
[OpenCV 2.4 InRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange)

I'm not sure about using a hue that overflows the 180 range but I think you can calculate them separately and then add the resulting Mats.

Comment: Any other color that is within 0 and 360 degrees hue I already can detect perfectly. It's the color (red) that overflows 360 degrees (InRange value 180 that is) that is difficult to detect with a single call.